# Next.js the button lost interaction when use <Suspense>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

```js
'use client'
import React, { Suspense } from "react";

const AsyncComponent = async () => {
  const data = await new Promise((r) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      r('Detail');
    }, 3000)
  }) as string;
  return <div>{data}</div>
};

function NormalComponent() {
  const handleClick = async () => {
    console.log('click!!');
  };
  return <div style={{border: '1px red solid', margin: '5px 0'}}>
    <button onClick={() => handleClick()}>Click me</button>
  </div>
}

export default function Page() {
  return <div>
    <Suspense fallback={<h2>Loading...</h2>}>
      {/* @ts-expect-error Async Server Component */}
      <AsyncComponent></AsyncComponent>
      <NormalComponent />
    </Suspense>
    <NormalComponent />
  </div>
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

When I visit the page, next returns 'Loading' and 'Click me'. After 3 seconds, all components are displayed, and I find that the button in Suspense does not respond when clicked, while the button outside Suspense can console normally after clicked. What is the cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use async functions directly in event handlers. Check updated NormalComponent component:-

```
function NormalComponent() {
  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log('click!!');
    setTimeout(() => {
      // Your async logic here
    }, 0); 
  };
  return (
    <div style={{ border: '1px red solid', margin: '5px 0' }}>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```